# how to integrate multiple .html pages into one page

Tags: html

I have multiple .html files that is been created through notepad.

the 1st .html page is link to the rest of the pages

I need a solution to have all the data inserted into 1st page of html but it should open the same way as they open while they are separate pages.

i don't want to create a particular folder and past all files into it so that it opens from there only.

if anyone has a solution please help me with the coding for the same.

Comment: do you have some code to show us?

Comment: @Leandro                                                                                                      <td><b><form action="1st.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Page2" />
</form></b></td>



    <td><b><form action="2nd.html">
  </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Page2">
</form></b></td>

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

i.e.

```
<iframe src="file1.html" width="400" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe src="file2.html" width="400" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe src="file3.html" width="400" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Presently am using this to combine multiple pages which are in one folder

<td><b><form action="1st.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Page2" />
</form></b></td>



    <td><b><form action="2nd.html">
  </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Page2">
</form></b></td>

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you are looking to create a dynamic web page. This means that you want to have several pages that look very similar but with different text and picture elements. To do this you will need to create a database with each element inside it. Then you can create a MENU page with all of the links to all of the pages on it. The links will be assigned to a dedicated ID in the database. When you click on the link it will open up your DYNAMIC web page. Then you can grab the correct database row with POST, run a QUERY on that particular row and then display the elements as you see fit. We can help you, but as Leandro stated, we need some code to be sure of what you are looking for.

Comment: I was using this codes to link the pages @JerryB                                                        <td><b><form action="1st.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Page2" />
</form></b></td>



    <td><b><form action="2nd.html">
  </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Page2">
</form></b></td>

Comment: to be honest am new to this and am learning through some websites if you don't mind me asking you how should i go about doing this array thing any code or link which i can refer to please

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array with a loop to help create a link to all of your pages...

```
$pages = array('page1','page2',);

foreach($pages as $value) {
echo "<a href='http://www.yourwebsite.com/$value'>$value</a><br>";
}
```